# LIST_ENTRY data structure in WinApi c++ explanation

Tags: c++, winapi, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to understand the purpose of the `LIST_ENTRY` structure. It's defined as:

```
typedef struct _LIST_ENTRY {
    struct _LIST_ENTRY *Flink;
    struct _LIST_ENTRY *Blink;
} LIST_ENTRY, *PLIST_ENTRY, PRLIST_ENTRY;
```

I've seen it used for finding import modules of a program:

```
PEB32* pPeb = GetPEB(pTeb);
LIST_ENTRY* ModuleListTail = &pPeb->Ldr->InMemoryOrderModuleList;
LIST_ENTRY* ModuleList = ModuleListTail->Flink;
do {
    unsigned char* ModuleAddr = (unsigned char*)ModuleList - (sizeof(LIST_ENTRY));
    _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY* entry = (_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY*)ModuleAddr;
    wchar_t Name[128];
    wmemcpy(Name, (wchar_t*)(void*)entry->BaseDllName.Buffer, 128);
    std::wcout << Name << '\n';
    ModuleList = ModuleList->Flink;
} while (ModuleList != ModuleListTail);
```

Why is the `ModuleList` pointer subtracted by the size of the structure?

`unsigned char* ModuleAddr = (unsigned char*)ModuleList - (sizeof(LIST_ENTRY));`

How is this structure used if it doesn't hold any data but pointers to other structures?

Comment: `_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY* entry = CONTAINING_RECORD(ModuleList , _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY, InMemoryOrderLinks);` must be. `LIST_ENTRY` was inside another structure, or another structure is inherited from `LIST_ENTRY` in this case we convert it address via `static_cast<MyStruct*>(entry)`

Comment: really this is pure *c/c++* question - how get address of structure from it embedded or inherited structure. concrete about list_entry - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/800404/Understanding-LIST-ENTRY-Lists-and-Its-Importance